# a problem with css postioning while live typing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, live, preview

i have this problem, im using live preview, while the user is typing they get to see thier text using jquery, but when the users starts typing it plays up with the divs around and starts to go crazy, i just want the whole page to be static while the user is typing,

the page is http://www.kornar.co.uk/customise.php

just start styping in the kornar Title Field!, and see what happens

thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `h1.kornarTitle`, remove:

```
float:left;
```

and replace with:

```
text-align:left;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

a) Remove float:left from h1.kornarTitle

or

b) Add clear:left to #leftPanel

To learn more about the css float property I recommend this comprehensive tutorial http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/